# Convert entries in column of pandas dataframe to title case only if they are all caps

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe of user entered names and addresses. Some users enter their NAMES AND ADDRESSES IN ALL CAPS. I  figured out how to convert a pandas dataframe column to title case ( df['last_name'] = df.last_name.str.title() ) but that messes up certain last names like McWhirter, which becomes Mcwhirter. Sorry if this is a noob question, but is there any way to selectively apply title case to column entries only if they are IN ALL CAPS?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Check all caps using `str.isupper` and filter according to that

```
df.loc[df.last_name.str.isupper(), 'last_name'] = df.last_name.str.title()
```